# Print response body when statusCode assert fails with restassured

Tags: java, rest, unit-testing, rest-assured, hamcrest

I'm using Hamcrest to unit test a REST API.

When I send a request, I often check for a `200` status code like this :

```
public void myTest() {
    url = "route/to/my/rest/api/";
    secured().when().get(url).then().statusCode(200);
}
```

But when I get a wrong code status, I only get an assertion error. Is there a way to automatically dump the response body (which contains the error) when the status code doesn't match ?

The `secured()` method :

```
public RequestSpecification secured() {
    return given().header("Authorization", "Bearer " + getAuth());
}
```

Comment: How can I adapt duplicated question's answer to my problem, as I'm using Restassured and not HttpURLConnection ?

Comment: One solution was to use `secured().when().post(url).then().log().ifValidationFails(LogDetail.BODY).statusCode(200);` [source](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#log-if-validation-fails)

Comment: I know some time has passed, but this question is in no way a duplicate of the linked one in the close reason. That's talking about a different library and doing a different thing.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments I used the following

```
secured().when().post(url).then().log().ifValidationFails(LogDetail.BODY).statusCode(200);
```

You can find the source in [the documentation](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#log-if-validation-fails)

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score -1):

You can add a message to the assertion when test fails:

```
.statusCode(describedAs("The test fails because ...", is(200)))
```